# Socket.io emitting multiple times to client

Tags: node.js, sockets, flutter, socket.io, foreground-service

Basically we use the socket to call deliverers for an app made in flutter, in the part of the app we made the socket work in the foreground service, however with the loss of internet connection the socket accumulates the emits and ends up crashing the app causing a memory leak.

I'm out of ideas to fix this now.

In the server side

```
global.ioDeliveryman = require('./socketio.js').init(deliveryManServer, {
        pingInterval: 10,
        pingTimeout: 5,
    });

global.ioDeliveryman.on('connect', function (socket) {
        socket.on('USER_CONNECTED', function(data){
            global.connectedDeliverymanUsers[data.id] = {socket_id: socket.conn.id , aceite: data.aceite}
        });

        socket.on('USER_DISCONNECTED', function(data){
            if(global.connectedDeliverymanUsers[data.id]){
                try {
                    global.ioDeliveryman.sockets.connected[global.connectedDeliverymanUsers[data.id].socket_id].disconnect();
                    delete global.connectedDeliverymanUsers[data.id]
                } catch (TypeError) {
                    console.log("Disconnect of undefined");
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

Client side

```
   if (!socket.connected) {
        conectar();

        var jsao;
        socket.on(describeEnum(SocketFunction.ALOCAR_ENTREGADOR), (data) async => {
          socket.emit(describeEnum(SocketFunction.PONG), { "id": userId } ),

          Vibration.vibrate(pattern: [1, 1000, 500, 2000]),

         //the var jsao is setted here

          NotificationUtils.showNotificationNovaCorrida(jsao),
          await FGS.ForegroundService.sendToPort(jsao),

          // check if app it's in the background aind wait 45 seconds to 
          Timer(Duration(seconds: 43), () async {
            await FGS.ForegroundService.sendToPort('{"order": {"funcao": "VERIFICAR_BACKGROUND"}}');
            if (isBackground) {
              Timer(Duration(seconds: 2), () {
                enviarAceiteEntregador(false, "${data["order"]["user_id"]}");
              });
            }
            isBackground = true;
          }),
        });
```

Emit inside a function callback on backend

here we do ping pong to see if the user is connected, but this memory leak sometimes happens
it`s done in a loop with callback to cycle through the available deliverers one by one until one of them accepts

```
    // PING
        try{
            if (alertMap.get(entregador.deliveryman_id.toString())) {
                callback();
                return;
            }
           //emit for deliveryman with socketId
            global.ioDeliveryman.to(socketId).emit('ALOCAR_ENTREGADOR', {order: actualOrder, clientName: clientName});
        } catch (TypeError) { console.log("Disconnect of undefined"); }

        // PONG
        pongMap.set(entregador.deliveryman_id.toString(), false);
```

everything works until the moment when the delivery person loses connection, then the socket starts to emit madly

Comment: When socket.io loses connection, it queues up any messages sent while it is disconnected.  So, if you're regularly send PONG messages from the client or any other type of message, they will queue up and when the connection is re-established, a flood of queued up messages will be sent.

Comment: I understand, but it gives the memory leak with the emit `ALOCAR_ENTREGADOR`, if that were it would not be just with the PONG?

Comment: There's not enough of the overall code layout for me to evaluate further.  I need to be able to see exactly when all these event handlers can get called.